# I can't load from cache in webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load from cache in `webview`:

I have tried this, but it's not working! Though I have added required permissions in Manifest.

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

**So, how to make `load from cache` works?**

Comment: `but it's not working` how do you know that it does not work ?

Comment: @AtefHares It wored =D

Comment: @AtefHares It wasn't catching the data, meaning, it was always in need of the internet ^^